# extract data from Bigquery using AWS lambda and store to S3

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, google-bigquery

I'm new to AWS lambda and I'd like to ask whether it is possible to extract data from bigquery using AWS lambda in CSV format and store this into AWS S3 bucket?

Anyone who has done this before? Can you please share the steps?

Thank you

Comment: This is entirely possible. A quick search finds lots of examples of connecting to Google BigQuery from AWS Lambda. What have you attempted so far?

Comment: None so far, I have nothing but idea. My idea is to use lambda and then authenticate bigquery ,specify the query for the data to extract, save to csv and upload to s3 using boto. Do you have any reference to share?

Comment: Your steps sound like exactly what you need to do. I suggest attempting it and coming back here with specific questions if you run into any issues.